# Is it possible in Gerrit to add a comment to a file that is not included the the patch set?

Tags: gerrit

Is it possible in Gerrit  to add a comment to a file that is not included the the patch set.
For example change is in file A and you want to add a comment to file B (which is not included in the change)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. If you try to add a comment to an unrelated file via the REST API it returns an error `file path/to/file not found in revision 123456,1`